# How to override "::-webkit-scrollbar" CSS rule and make scrollbar visible again

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I use the following rule to make scrollbars invisible:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

How do I override this rule to make scrollbars visible again? I tried the following:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: initial; }
```

In this case scrollbars reserve their space, but the thumb is not visible.

See a short demo [here](http://codepen.io/ermakovich/pen/eDqrw).

Comment: hi, does this link work for you?
http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/

Comment: @KheemaPandey My question is how to make scrollbar visible again after making it invisible. I haven't found an answer by the link provided.

Comment: @s.ermakovich: Were you able to get this working? I have a similar situation.

Comment: @TheRock, unfortunately no. It seems that `::-webkit-scrollbar` completely overrides default scrollbar, and there is no way to reset this override.

Answer (score 2):

try

::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: hidden; }

and

::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: visible; }

Edit:

Though, that would keep the space... So, add "width: 0 !important;"

Comment: I've messed around with it: it appears that when you "unhide" the thing, the entire style of the scrollbar is overwritten with *blank. When you style the webkit-scrollbar yourself, it works. It's a bit circuitous, but it works. In the example it works with a media-query, but I don't know how you want to implement it? http://jsfiddle.net/KTmkD/1/

Comment: The problem is that I don't need custom scrollbar. I just want to reset it to default style.

Comment: @s.ermakovich Webkit-scrollbar replaces the default scrollbar, as far as I know, so that's why it's so tricky to unhide the thing. I did find this, though. Maybe this will help? http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

After a while, i wanted to hide the scroll bar for my `.horizontal-scroll` class. This one worked for me:

Before:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #f4f7f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f4f7f5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #222823;
}

.horizontal-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

After:

```
html::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #f4f7f5;
}

html:has(.horizontal-scroll)::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f4f7f5;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #222823;
}
```