# How to show webkit scrollbar which has been hidden using display:none css property?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

On a page I am having a webkit scrollbar which has been hidden using display: none css property.

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

In one of my app level css files I tried to override the above css rule, but I wasn't able to display the scrollbar

I tried changing the css but I couldn't the get exact scrollbar which would have been there if display: none property was not present.

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     width: 7px;
     display: block;
}

#element::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

The above css made the scroll bar visible but it gave me ugly scroll bar (probably due the css rules I have used).

Is there a simple way in which I can display the webkit scrollbar which would been there if the display:none property was not present.
I can not change the display:none as it is being inherited by my app.
I can only over-ride that rule.

**EDIT:**

An exactly similar question was asked [How to override "::-webkit-scrollbar" CSS rule and make scrollbar visible again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985485/how-to-override-webkit-scrollbar-css-rule-and-make-scrollbar-visible-again), but it seems that also doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Use a class like `allow-scroll`, then select with `#element:not(.allow-scroll)::-webkit-scrollbar` for your `display: none`. Then just add/remove the class with JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately `::-webkit-scrollbar` only supports in Chrome Browser !

Comment: @AtalShrivastava: I am facing this problem on chrome only.

Comment: @DJDavid98: I didn't exactly get what you meant by "then select with #element:not(.allow-scroll)::-webkit-scrollbar for your display: none". Can it be done by css alone?

Comment: [Webkit Vertical Scrollbar](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/) This could help you on better understanding on webkit scrollbar

Comment: `#element:not(.allow-scroll)::-webkit-scrollbar` this means your element which is not containing `.allow-scroll` class hide it.@TheRock

Comment: @TheRock It can only be done in pure CSS if you use native selectors like `:hover` or `:focus`, but in this case I don't think those will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
*:not(.excluded-element)::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```

reads as: apply it to everything except the `.excluded-element`

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but somewhat working approach is proposed in this SuperUser answer: https://superuser.com/a/1685163/814616

The catch is in reverting not only `display` property, but all scrollbar related rules. That resets all colors, though, so they need to be redefined.

Answer (score -1):

If the display:none is what it's hiding it why don't you just overwrite the display instead of adding that other properties?

Try overwriting the display with the different values it can has:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: I tried all the options display property can have, but none seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Does not seem to work, as pointed out in the comments.**

I was able to restore the scrollbars using

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: unset;
}
```

Comment: Not even this works. I've tried every possible value but it seems if you have set `display:none` it is non-reversible. Same conclusion as @TheRock