# Iframe does not show scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

Can't seem to make the iframe appear with a scroll-bar.

Go to https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/accountant
email: qa@billiving.com
pass: 111111

Reload the list with F5, then click new invoice on the right side. The content is lengthy but doesn't show the scroll-bar.

My css uses the following:

```
.frm {
  position: fixed; width: 100%; height:100vh; overflow-y:scroll !important; overflow-x:hidden !important; 

}
```

html is as follows:

```
<iframe frameborder="5" class="frm" ng-src="{{trustSrc(url)}}" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hidden scrollbars in ionic.app.css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

I don't know if it is possible to override this style so probably you have to remove it. [Similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985485/how-to-override-webkit-scrollbar-css-rule-and-make-scrollbar-visible-again)

Comment: Great :-) Can you explain the method of how you found this? I tried going up the DOM using styles tab in Chrome but it seems hard to find. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to remove `<link>`s from DOM and then, by removing styles one by one, finally I came to that declaration. Tough job but we learn throughout life :)